# convert lists to data frames

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I'm a beginner in R. I'm working in a data to expand my knowledge especially in data manipulation.

The task is to split my data set based on a parameter(column). Then to calculate the standard deviation for each group, then to provide some graphs. I did split my data set to about 3000 list, but I'm stuck in converting the lists into separate data sets so I can collect the SD for each data set. Or if there is an efficient way to do it in one code.

this is what I did so far.

```
xx <- read.table("NetworkRail1.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE)

selected <- select(xx,ID, Location, Top70m)

splitNR <- split(selected, selected$Location %% 0.125)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is to save the different components of the list separately, you can try this:

```
list2env(splitNR, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend this. R can work with lists of related data much easier than trying to manipulate several thousand free-floating objects with `assign` `get` etc.

Comment: @thelatemail I just answered the question of OP, which says `"I'm stuck in converting the lists into separate data sets"`. I'm not recommending it.

Comment: Thank you all , as I said I'm a beginner and don't know how to deal with my tasks. My data set is about 150000 rows and 19 columns and I have to divide it into different groups based on a column so I did split it into each 1/8 of mile as required to find out the SD of another column(Top70) for each 1/8 of mile. Then to deal with SD > 2.2 and provide solutions and graphs.